# FeatureGroup is checked or not Folium Map Python

Tags: python, folium

I puted a FeatureGroup on a Folium map in LayerControl. How do I know if this FeautureGroup is checked?

My code:

```
groupp = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Name")
groupp.add_to(map)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(map)
```

I want something like:

```
if groupp.isChecked():
     print("groupp is checked")
```

I want to print in console a message when i check/uncheck ''groupp'' from LayerControl.

Help me and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Do you want a marker when the user click, it says something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a marker when clicked, a popup message appears near it, you can do something like that:

```py
from folium import FeatureGroup, LayerControl, Map, Marker

m = Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=5, tiles="Stamen Terrain")

groupp = FeatureGroup(name="Some icons")
Marker(location=[45, -102.6625], popup="this is checked").add_to(groupp)

groupp.add_to(m)
LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

The output should be like that.

[image]

The full documentation for the FeatureGroup class within the folium package [is here](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html?highlight=featuregroup#folium.map.FeatureGroup)

Comment: Look at this photo: https://i.postimg.cc/1XdmR2pV/2.png I want to print in console a message when i check/uncheck ''groupp''. Sorry for bad english

Comment: What console? Javascript console in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: Console from jupyter notebook , just a print("Something") in console when i check/uncheck ''gropupp'' from LayerControl.

Comment: @Cliffhanger Interesting! I believe it is not covered by folium yet, check this thread on their GitHub repo https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/848.

Comment: I am not sure if this answer on the stack exchange site would benefit you; however, it worth read and try https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313382/click-event-on-maps-with-folium-and-information-retrieval